# Does AsyncFunction work on KeyedStream?

Tags: apache-flink

I didn't find, so I'm asking about it! Is there anyway to apply an `AsyncFunction` on `KeyedStream`s ? If yes, does it keep the order per key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not supported yet. Flink has `RichAsyncFunction`, but state access has been disabled, since the key may get changed while processing the element(there are multiple threads for aysnc operator).