# Value state within asynchronous function calls for keyed streams

Tags: java, asynchronous, async-await, apache-flink

It seems like the `RichAsyncFunction` in Flink [does not support keyed streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47728355/does-asyncfunction-work-on-keyedstream). I have a use case where I used a client to lookup a service for some result, cache it within value state as I have many duplicate keys in the upstream where the results are the same. (Think some attribute related to a user, but that user has multiple events and I need to join that attribute to the user event each time).

I originally used a blocking client to do what I need, and that worked for a while under low traffic, however it has gotten to a state where the resources applied are no longer sufficient.

I re-implemented the client to return a `CompletableFuture<Result>` object when invoked, and I want to know what is the best way to integrate that into a `KeyedProcessFunction` so I can take advantage of asynchronous function calling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I have done is first partition the DataStream, then do my own in-memory caching (using Guava) inside of the async function. The cache is lost on a restart, but that should be fine (just some efficiency loss on rebuilding the cache).

There is another approach that is a lot more complex. You save the output of the async function somewhere (e.g. Kafka), and then use that topic as a (keyed) source that you can join with your pre-enriched datastream. So this happens upstream from the async function. You then use a side output for cache hits, which is unioned downstream with the enriched stream.

Using Kafka as a sink and a source for the same workflow lets you implement a cyclic DAG (an iteration) without running into the current limitation Flink has with checkpoints/exactly once and iterations.

These days I might try Paimon as the sink/source, since it would have lower operational overhead versus Kafka.

Comment: Thanks for writing up the "put the cache in Kafka" approach. I've considered (and suggested) this, but I've never seen it in the wild. Have you?

Comment: Hi David - I implemented this for a client's project, though I've never seen it used in an open source project.

Comment: I am curious about your suggestion for the cyclic DAG. I understand your point of sinking the async function call result to Kafka, but if the Flink job then consumes from it, it would supposedly "consume" the event and would no longer be available, so I don't think it would act as a cache. If I don't commit offsets, it would be "available" but then there might be a lot of duplicate events since my async function doesn't know what it processed. (Unless I keep a cache of processed events...? But that wouldn't be optimal either since the stream is not keyed.)

Comment: When you consume the event from Kafka, you'd save it in (keyed) state that's used for enrichment. This state is used inside of the upstream (to the async function) to handle cache lookups.